# php readfile printing file to screen and downloading

Tags: php

This is a simple toy script, but I'm having issues with it.  I'm trying to have the user download a file using readfile() but also have the script write to the page.  Upon executig this script in the browser the file IS downloaded, but it appears that the file is being printed to the screen as well.  Additionally I'm getting the following errors:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php:8) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 11
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php:8) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 12
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php:8) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php:8) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 14

Code is as follows:

```
<?php 
$file = './1966.xlsx';

echo "thanks";


    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit();
?>
```

Do I need to declare headers for the entire script?  I got the header and readfile() parts from the php manual online.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting those errors because you're sending content to the browser before sending the headers.

To fix this, you need to remove `echo "thanks";`.

Comment: Is there a way to render text to the screen as well, or would that have to be with a follow-on script?

Comment: @WildBill:  You would have a separate page page display your message.  In that page's header, include a `<meta>` refresh with the location of this page.

Comment: @spidEY:  I would say no, as that message may be included with the downloaded data.

Comment: "remove `echo "thanks"`" is the most poetic stack overflow accepted answer of all time.